# Get '.name a' with html agility pack?

Tags: html-agility-pack

I am trying to get all links of a link when its parent class is name_of_box. I wrote the below but got nothing. How do i do this? With css i believe i can select it with `.name_of_box a`

```
var ls = htmldoc.DocumentNode.Elements("//div[@class='name_of_box']//a[@href]");
```

Answer (score 0):

HtmlAgilityPack doesn't have the ability to directly query an attribute value. You have to loop over the list of anchor nodes. Here's one way:

```
var ls = new List<string>(); 
var nodes = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='name_of_box']//a");
nodes.ToList().ForEach(a => ls.Add(a.GetAttributeValue("href", "")));
```

But there is an [experimental build](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/releases/view/46681) you can look at, that will let you directly query an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It could be easily done with [fizzler](http://code.google.com/p/fizzler/) - a .NET library to select items from a node tree based on a CSS selector. The default implementation is based on HTMLAgilityPack and selects from HTML documents.

See:

```
var ls = htmldoc.DocumentNode.QuerySelectorAll(".name_of_box a");
```